# Why do the pictures disappear when I reload the page in Django?

Tags: python, django, apache, mod-wsgi

Site on Django. Configuration mod_wsgi-express inside virtualenv + apache2. I started the page through the command `python manage.py runmodwsgi --setup-server --port 8888 --server-root = / home / user / virtualenv / mod_wsgi-express-80`. Everything was OK the first time. The problem appeared when I started to reload the page (CTRL + R). What can cause problems?

Here is my apache2 configuration file for vhost.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        ServerName example.com
        ServerAlias www.example.com
        ProxyPass / http://124.124.13.134:8888/
        ProxyPassReverse / http://124.124.13.134:8888/
        RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Port 80

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Your `ProxyPass` command is on port 8000 but your `runmodwsgi` on port 8888? Also what images are not loaded? static files? or media (uploaded) files? And if you're using Apache2 directly anyway, why don't you just follow [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/) and skip mod_wsgi-express entirely?

Comment: I use this solution because I have two versions of django on the server (python2 and 3). Apache mod_wsgi does not support two versions, so I had to use such a solution. An error with ports is a typo. The problem concerns the media.

Comment: Media files aren’t served by django in production. You should add a configuration in apache to serve your media files directly, as shown in the link I posted in my previous comment.

Comment: I added the url alias for the / media / folder, which turned out to be the solution to the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Media files aren’t served by django in production. You should add a configuration in apache to serve your media files directly, using an alias for `/media/` (or whatever you defined `MEDIA_URL` to be) to point to your media directory (which you defined with `MEDIA_ROOT`).

An example is shown in the [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/).